# Create DB statement - error on DB name

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a DB programmatically using:

```
String DBName = "DB name 2015-02-01";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE " + DBName);
```

but I get this error:

```
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name 2015-02-01' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I do to create DB with that `DBName`?

Thanks

Comment: DBName don't have to contain empty spaces + [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String,%20int)) is wrong method call.

Comment: ok thanks, so how can I create DB with that `DBName` (with empty spaces)?

Comment: i'm not sure it's possible because of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) specifications.

Comment: @drgPP why is `executeUpdate` is wrong ? thats how you create the db - `int Result=statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");` is clearly how you create the db from java. do not see whats wrong here

Comment: @FredericHenri you are right, it works, the API says the following: **Parameter** `sql - an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.` I have not read the second part about DDL statement. I wanted to edit my comment.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree this is bad practice to have space in name but its not forbidden as others can say. the restrictions are documented here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html and only a space at the end is forbidden

you can even mess with table names with space - for example the following works:

```
fhenri@machine:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.22 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database `db with space`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> use `db with space`;
Database changed
mysql> create table `table with space` (column1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,03 sec)

mysql> select * from `table with space`;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

From Java, you need to add the ` character (backtick character, not to confused with simple quote ')

```
String DBName = "`DB name 2015-02-01`";
```

Comment: This demonestrates my assumption was false. Great example.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work in java.
I says: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DB name 2015-02-01'' at line 1`

Comment: @Frank, I might check later, do you use ` (backtick) or ' (quote), it seems you have use quote while backtick needs to be used